# Calculate the difference between row values as a percentage

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a table that has a sales figure in a total column. This is repeated for 5 years worth of data.

```
Year | Sales £
_____|___________
2013 | £100,000
2014 | £150,000
2015 | £135,000
2016 | £200,000
```

I would like to add a new column that shows the difference between each row.

```
Year | Sales £  | % diff
_____|__________|_________
2013 | £100,000 |
2014 | £150,000 |   50
2015 | £135,000 |  (10)
2016 | £200,000 |   48.1
```

The data is returned using an MDX query.

**I would like to do this with an expression in the report, is this possible?**

I appreciate any suggestions, but would like to know if this can be done at report level.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The expression looks like this:

```
select t.*,
       100 * (sales - lag(sales) over (order by year)) / lag(sales*1.0) over (order by year)
from t;
```

You can format the numbers at the application level.

This expression can be simplified to:

```
    select t.*,
           100 * (-1 + sales / lag(sales*1.0) over (order by year))
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier to do it in the dataset, rather than an expression in the report. Using `LAG`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (2013,100000),(2014,150000),(2015,135000),(2016,200000)) V([Year],Sales))
SELECT [Year], Sales,
       CONVERT(decimal(12,4),CONVERT(decimal(12,4),Sales) / LAG(Sales) OVER (ORDER BY [Year])) - 1 AS Diff
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @x table ([Year] int, Sales int)
insert into @x values 
(2013, 100000),
(2014, 150000),
(2015, 135000),
(2016, 200000)

select [YEAR],
       Sales,
       cast(round(100.00*(Sales - LAG(Sales, 1) over (order by Year))/LAG(Sales, 1) over (order by Year), 2) as float) as [% diff]
from @x
```